# Remove a array element from json file using python

Tags: python, json

I want to remove whole **Element** array from this below json file. I am quite new in json. Please help.

**Input**:

ABCD12:

```
{

   "code": "ab11",

   "Number": 123456,

   "Name": "aaaaaa",

   "Element": [

             {
                          "abc": "123", 
                          "Center": "123",
                          "Description": "your description here", 
              },
              {
                          "Cdf": "456", 
                          "Color": "blue",
                          "Shape": "round", 
              }

],
  "Animal": "tiger",

  "Bird": "eagle",

  "Flower": "rose"
  }
```

CDEF34:

```
{

   "code": "cd12",

   "Number": 7891011,

   "Name": "bbbbb",

   "Element": [

             {
                          "abc": "345", 
                          "Center": "456ab",
                          "Description": "your description", 
              },
              {
                          "Cdf": "567", 
                          "Color": "grey",
                          "Shape": "circle", 
              }

],
  "Animal": "dog",

  "Bird": "crow",

  "Flower": "sunflower"
  }
```

**Output**:

ABCD12:

```
{

   "code": "ab11",

   "Number": 123456,

   "Name": "aaaaaa",

  "Animal": "tiger",

  "Bird": "eagle",

  "Flower": "rose"

  }
```

CDEF34:

```
{

   "code": "cd12",

   "Number": 7891011,

   "Name": "bbbbb",


  "Animal": "dog",

  "Bird": "crow",

  "Flower": "sunflower"

  }
```

I tried to keep the json in a file called file.json and executed below code in python

```
import json

with open("file.json") as f:

       data= json.load(f)

f.pop(data["wbsElement"]) 

with open("file.json", "w") as f: 

       json.dump(data, f)
```

But no help.

Comment: Why do you think files have a `.pop()` method. What would it even do? Files are just strings of bytes. They have no structure. The `data` dict does

Comment: Python dictionaries have a built-in *pop* function. Also take a look at *del*

Answer (score 0):

You executed:

```
data = json.load(f)

f.pop(data["wbsElement"])
```

What you wanted was something along the lines of

```
del data["wbsElement"]
```

or

```
data.pop("wbsElement")
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop

Answer (score 0):

Because `"Element"` is a nested value and not a key, one approach is to loop through the values. Your code should look like:

```py
import json

with open("file.json") as f:
    data= json.load(f)

for obj in data.values():
    del obj['Element']
    # or
    # obj.pop("Element")

with open("file.json", "w") as f: 
    json.dump(data, f)
```